# Active records on codeigniter page

Tags: codeigniter

I want print a table from database on view page with where condition, means I want print table of student where class is seven and fee status is paid.

How we do this?

i tried it but not work:

```
<?php 
                $students   =   $this->db->get_where('student' , array('status' => paid,'class_id'=>7))->result_array();
                foreach($students as $row):?>
```

Comment: Show your attempts what you have tried so far.

Comment: See the doc https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: See new BCIT Codeigniter user guide here http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: Just search the documentation of codeigniter and you will get all the required knowledge..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this code to find the answer for you Please see it and try it out

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('tasks', array('description' => 7,'status' => 1));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($query->result_array());
```

> change your array element as this since paid is a string it must be in quots

```
array('description' => "paid",'class_id'=>7)
```

Comment: @prince kumar Please research more before posting questions

Comment: @princekumar accept the answer if you got the output

Comment: I tried It but not work <?php 
                $students = $this->db->get_where('invoice' , array('status' => paid,'student_id'=>$student_id))->result_array();
                foreach($students as $row):?>

Comment: @princekumar what is it that you are getting from the query?

Comment: sorry please see above in my question for right query. it edited again.

Comment: @princekumar i have edited the answer. This query worked for me in getting data from table having the fields as shown

Comment: @princekumar paid is a string so give it in quots

Comment: @princekumar A small reminder please be carefull while posting such questions. Because its answer was easily available in google. This will force  others to think that you havnt done any research on this topic and will downvote your question.